# Reference JavaScript file in other project

Tags: aptana, aptana3

In an Aptana Studio 3 web project, is it possible to use JS libraries located in a different project?

I'm trying to create a JavaScript library and put it under source control, then create an example project that uses APIs in my library. As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this. It appears to me that all of my HTML/CSS/JS files need to be located in the same project.

Am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT**

To clarify: if I have everything in 1 project, my folder structure looks like this

```
- Project\
   - index.html
   - JS/
       - myAwesomeLibrary.js
       - script.js
```

And I would reference my JS files like this

```
<script src="JS/myAwesomeLibrary.js"></script>
<script src="JS/script.js"></script>
```

What I want to do is move myAwesomeLibrary into its own Aptana project:

```
- Library\
   - JS\
       -myAwesomeLibrary.js
- Project\
   - index.html
   - JS\
       - script.js
```

How do I make this work in HTML?

Comment: Have you tried Project > Properties > Project References?

Comment: Yep. I added a project reference, but then how do I add the javascript library to my HTML? Using <script> tags, I can only set the src attribute to a path in a (sub)directory of the project I'm working on.

Comment: What do you mean you can only set the src within your project? You just mean the external libraries aren't included in content assist?

Comment: Exactly. I don't know what value to use for the "src" attribute if my script is located in a different Aptana project.

EDIT: Actually I misread that the first time. I meant that I don't know how to include my external library if the library file is not inside the same Aptana project.

Comment: @SarahKemp I tried to better explain what I'm doing with some examples.

Comment: I fear I'm misunderstanding your problem. Are you asking about Aptana or about how to use the script tag in HTML?

Comment: I'm using Aptana, and I'm asking about how to configure its built-in web server to serve both files in the project I'm working on as well as files in the project which contains myAwesomeLibrary.js. Why? Because I don't want to create a copy of my library in every project that depends on it.

Comment: If what I'm asking is at all possible, I'd also like to know what the script tag would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where your Library project is located relative to your Project project. If they are both in the same parent folder, the src for your js could be as simple as

`<script src="../Library/JS/myAwesomeLibrary.js"></script>`

Meaning, go up one folder past where my current file is and then look for a folder called 'Library'. You can also use an absolute path using the address the internal browser uses - though you will have to change this for the final server. The absolute path would look something like:

`<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Library/JS/myAwesomeLibrary.js"></script>`

Keep in mind, this may work in Aptana's internal browser, but your paths may change once you get the final server if the Library, for instance,  is located in a different virtual host than the Project.

Comment: Brilliant! I was thrown off by the lack of code assist when starting the path with `..`, but apparently it works anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: there is a way to make Aptana synchronize files between two projects by setting up a new connection with the source set to project 'Library' and destination project 'Project'.

I might actually use this method instead as it allows greater control over which project gets library updates and when, while also removing the need to set different script tags on the development server.

Comment: I could, but your answer more accurately answers what I was initially trying to do. I'm merely suggesting a workaround. I suppose that each answer has its con's and pro's.